# clear check box and hide image when clicked on drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to uncheck the check box and hide the image once i have selected the next drop down menu

[Fiddle Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kunz/uzo8ruoy/)

i do not know how to go about it if some one can help me out please

Comment: like this one https://fiddle.jshell.net/uzo8ruoy/5/ ?? let me know so i can post as answer, thanx.

Comment: yes just like that but since i have a lot of drop down boxes and a alot of check boxes cant there be something like to hide all images or somthing
or do i have to do it one by one

Comment: if you want to hide many images then try to play with class. give all images the same class you want to hide and then use that class instead of id, wont it work??

Comment: created a demo. check this https://fiddle.jshell.net/uzo8ruoy/17/ and let me know is it ok or not?

Comment: anywho this answer helped me so i wil just code one by one its okay but works just as fine :D

Comment: should i post my answer with detail so you can accept as answer or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uncheck checkbox use $("#chkbox").prop("checked", false);

For hiding image use $("#image").css("display", "none");

Here is link to updated code: https://fiddle.jshell.net/uzo8ruoy/7/